# Обработка исключений и вывод в JSON

Tags: php, yii2

У меня есть API в котором нужно возвращать ошибки клиенту с помощью исключений. Например, клиент запросил несуществующий документ и приложение выбросило исключение:

```
public function actionGet($docId)
{
    return (array) $this->findModel($docId);
}

protected function findModel($id)
{
    if (($model = Doc::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    }
    throw new NotFoundHttpException("Документ {$id} не найден");
}
```

В таком случаи, yii должен вернуть ответ следующего вида:

```
{
    "success": false, // Успен/Не успех
    "message": "Документ 10 не найден", //Текст из исключения
}
```

Вместо этого yii возвращает свой дефолтный вывод который меня не устраивает

```
{
    "name":"Not Found",
    "message":"Документ 10 не найден",
    "code":0,
    "status":404
}
```

Проблема в том, что я не могу найти способ как кастомизировать вывод исключений. Пытался использовать `errorHandler`, он даже не срабатывает. Как я понял - `errorHandler` не работает если `Yii::$app->response->format` установлен в `yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;`.

Возможно вы спросите, зачем это нужно? Это просто удобно и уменьшает количество кода.

Comment: Как вариант добавить свой обработчик исключений , например 
```NotFoundDocument``` в место  ```NotFoundHttpException```

Comment: @or_die в этом то всё и дело - я не знаю способа как добавить обработчик) throw ведь выполняется на уровне экшена, а ниже по стеку я опустится не могу

Comment: @or_die формат вывода формируется где-то в недрах yii (который мне нужно изменить),  NotFoundDocument ничего не изменит.

Comment: Не знаю, как там в yii , но мне кажется все таки можно. 
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/HttpException.php
Создашь по образу, называешь его, как больше нравится,  Переделываешь как тебе нужно, подключаешь и кидаешь еспешен с этим объектом 

Там есть метод return Response::$httpStatuses[$this->statusCode];, возвращаешь в место его, то что тебе нужно. А потом 

throw new MyErrorExeption

Comment: @XYZ, а может вовсе не использовать исключения для таких случаев? Предлагаю для несуществующего документа  создавать и возвращать параметизированный инстанс класса модели несуществующего документа (что-то вроде такого: ```return new DocumentNotFoundModel($success, $message)```